# Mini2dx - Can't find tutorials

Tags: java, 2d, game-engine, mini2dx

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but i looked for a new 2D game engine and decided that i want to use Mini2Dx. It is a 2D Java Game Engine which has some already prebuilt features like UI-Elements, Particles, etc. The engine itself is based on LIBGDX.
Even though i really want to use it, I can't find any  tutorials. Except for  a spanish tutorial, that I don't understand.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkDpfBCo_XI&list=PLTd5ehIj0goOYxN4HotZAY4uphbgFTQ_c

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sadly mini2Dx is not in trends so don't have video tutorial in English.

But you can use [documentation](https://github.com/mini2Dx/mini2Dx/wiki) on his github wiki also you can check this [game](https://github.com/mini2Dx/mini2Dx-sample-tictactoe) for reference that is sample game of mini2Dx.

There is also active community on his [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mini2Dx/) page, that may help you in your development.